# why electrons don't stop moving after passing load resistance

Tags: resistors

If an electron does work to pass a circuit component (load resistance), why don't they eventually stop moving after passing load resistance and transferring all of its energy

Comment: who said they transfer all of their energy?

Comment: I suppose one possible answer is that it is because there's still a little energy left over and a wire is a very, very easy path that requires very little remaining work to traverse.

Comment: What if I told you that the electrons **do not carry the energy** but instead, their **movement** is where the energy is. The electricity company does not deliver electrons to you, they just make them **move**.

Comment: Why doesn't water stop flowing in your heating circuit when it reaches the radiator / heater? Answer: because it's current. What comes in must go out.

Comment: They also would not be able to stop, as that would violate Heisenberg's uncertainty principle: ΔxΔp > h/2π. The position of an  electron with zero impulse could be anywhere in the universe.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_cradle#/media/File:Newtons_cradle_animation_book_2.gif
Electrons hardly move (newton's balls in this analogy), but the energy they transfer moves very quickly.

Answer (score 1):

You are thinking the electrons do the work, they don't, they carry the energy.

Instead you should think of electrons as a chain. Like a chain electrons move around in loops. The voltage source powers that chain making it move and power will be transferred to the load(s).

The chain itself just keeps on going round and round, or loops back and forward in an AC drive.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Lets answer by a counter question by transfering your original question to mechanics:

Why does a car wheel NOT stop moving after passing the point where is touches the street and transfering all the energy?

It transfers energy **by passing** and of course it has to go on moving after the point of contact where the work is done. The same is true for electrical current and a resistor.